# Messaging: If there is not connection, send message when recover it

Tags: android, connection, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging, messaging

I have created an instant messaging app for Android. But now I want to add some functionality:

If the users have not internet connection at the moment they try to send the message, it will have to be sent when the users recover the connection.

I guess the best way to do it is with a broadcast receiver. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You could keep track of all the fail requests once the connection fails and set a thread who runs in the background that tries to send the failed messages. Let's say every 10-20 seconds or more. And if fails the thread goes to sleep. Once all the messages are sent you close the thread and a new thread starts only if a message fails. if another message fails you check int he Queue. You could also use of PriorityQueue to schedule the messages in a easier way

You can Get the Network State like this.

```
 public boolean getInternetState() {

   ConnectivityManager conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        DialogFragment noInternet = new NoInternetDialog();
        noInternet.show(getFragmentManager(), "noInternet");
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the you can show a  DialogFragment to the user which will take him to wifi-settings or wherever you want.

```
public class NoInternetDialog extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("No Internet Connection! Please Check your Internet Connection and try Again!")
            .setPositiveButton("Open Wi-fi Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                }
            });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

```
if(getInternetState()) {
      // do network request here
}
```

Comment: I dont want to show wifi settings to the user. I want to save the message somewhere(SQLite for example) and try to send it again when the user recover the connection.

Comment: Is it not your background thread solution a resource consuming way?

Comment: Depend on how often you send the request. Every 20 seconds or so you check if the user has connection and sends the request. if he doesn't has internet you sleep the thread for another 20 seconds. When the request is done you can terminate the thread. I don't think would be very consuming considering all the processing power that cellphones have these days.